# Identify duplicate cosecutive rows in a list, if the value in first column changes then, restart the identifying duplicate in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to identify if the number gets repeated in multiple instances as shown in column A.  However when used =IF(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)=1,"x","xx"), this is giving one time identified result only, rest it is repeated as duplicate.  I need to restart the identification afresh when the value in column A changes. Shown both what I have got in column B and what is desired in column C

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in `B2`:

```
=IF(A2=A1,"xx","x")
```

---

And though not asked for `=IF(A2=A1,B1&"x","x")` might give a better insight.

Comment: Thanks JvdV.  This shows I am overthinking for the simplest solution. :)